# Rate limit policy with Microsoft.AspNetCore.RateLimiting middleware needs to share state in kubernetes

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, kubernetes

With rate limit policy with Microsoft.AspNetCore.RateLimiting middleware, state is kept in memory, so running the middleware in Kubernetes will mean that every pod has it's own counter.

Q: How I could share the state of the rate limiter across the pods?

I guess I need custom implementation of some part of the policy. Examples are welcome.